# How do I split a user-defined sentence into words in C++ using substr and find?

Tags: c++, string

I used this function but it is wrong.

```
for (int i=0; i<sen.length(); i++) {
    if (sen.find (' ') != string::npos) {
        string new = sen.substr(0,i);
    }
cout << "Substrings:" << new << endl;
}
```

Thank you! Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: As a start, don't use 'new' as a variable name. It is already used in the language for something else.

Comment: Oh so it is a reserved word. I see. Thank you!

Comment: @CandaceParker: Please tell us what exactly is wrong with your function. Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does is deliver bad results?

Comment: and you use `sen.find(' ')` which will always find the _same_ space, no matter how many times you call it. And you use `sen.substr(0,i)` which will return the whole of the string up to i instead of only the latest word.

Comment: I think you should really start with [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), since you seem to be missing some very basic knowledge. Believe me, you're in for a world of hurt if you try to learn C++ without any good book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a keyword in C++, so first step is to not use that as a variable name.

After that, you need to put your output statement in the "if" block, so that it can actually be allowed to access the substring.  Scoping is critical in C++.

Answer (score 0):

First: this cannot compile because `new` is a language keyword.

Then you have a loop running through every character in the string so you shouldn't need to use `std::string::find`. I would use `std::string::find`, but then the loop condition should be different.

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate over the string, `find` already does this. It starts to search from the beginning by default, so once we found a space, we need to start the next search from this found space:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;

//find first space
size_t start = 0, end = sen.find(' ');

//as long as there are spaces
while(end != std::string::npos)
{
    //get word
    words.push_back(sen.substr(start, end-start));

    //search next space (of course only after already found space)
    start = end + 1;
    end = sen.find(' ', start);
}

//last word
words.push_back(sen.substr(start));
```

Of course this doesn't handle duplicate spaces, starting or trailing spaces and other special cases. You would actually be better off using a stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::istringstream stream(sen);
std::vector<std::string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream), 
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

You can then just put these out however you like or just do it directly in the loops without using a vector:

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter=
    words.begin(); iter!=words.end(); ++iter)
    std::cout << "found word: " << *iter << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use substr and find, so if this is homework and you have to use that then this won't be a good answer... but I do believe it's the better way to do what you're asking in C++.  It's untested but should work fine.

```
//Create stringstream and insert your whole sentence into it.
std::stringstream ss;
ss << sen;

//Read out words one by one into a string - stringstream will tokenize them
//by the ASCII space character for you.
std::string myWord;
while (ss >> myWord)
    std::cout << myWord << std::endl;  //You can save it however you like here.
```

If it is homework you should tag it as such so people stick to the assignment and know how much to help and/or not help you so they don't give it away :)